Как сделать вывод тегов относящихся только к текущей категории, в категории товаров Prestashop 1.6
Подскажите пожалуйста как можно сделать вывод тегов товаров, которые относятся только к текущей категории? В престе по-умолчанию теги выводятся все сразу...
есть такой код вставляю в category.tpl:
<div class="producttags"> 
    
        {foreach from=$products item=product name=products}
            {foreach from=Tag::getProductTags($product.id_product) key=k item=v}
                {foreach from=$v item=value}
                    {if isset($tags) && !empty($tags) && $tags > 0}
                    <a href="{$link->getPageLink('search', true, NULL, "tag={$value|urlencode}")}">{$value|escape:html:'UTF-8'}</a>
                    {else}
                    {l s='Пока что здесь ничего нет' mod='blocktags_mod'}
                    {/if}
                {/foreach}
            {/foreach}
        {/foreach}
        
    </div>

Он выводит все как нужно, НО также выводит и пустые значения. Т.е. если в товаре тег не заполнен, то он все равно выводится как пустая ссылка...Подскажите пожалуйста как можно выводить теги для конкретной категории, если они заполнены в товаре, и не выводить пустые значения.

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! Мы заметили, что ваш вопрос требует некоторых уточнений. Прежде чем его опубликовать, рекомендуем ознакомиться с справкой о том, как правильно задавать вопросы: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

$tags - откуда берётся переменная?

@DeniskaSosiSka Подтягивается отсюда {foreach from=Tag::getProductTags($product.id_product) .
Хотя вот этот участок кода
' {if isset($tags) && !empty($tags) && $tags > 0}
<a href="{$link->getPageLink('search', true, NULL, "tag={$value|urlencode}")}">{$value|escape:html:'UTF-8'}
{else}
{l s='Пока что здесь ничего нет' mod='blocktags_mod'}
{/if}'
можно изменить на:
' <a href="{$link->getPageLink('search', true, NULL, "tag={$value|urlencode}")}">{$value|escape:html:'UTF-8'}'
